# How to redraw a python plot after raw_input

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to compose a plot by adding functions sequentially. The idea is to add each new line after pressing a key. Something easily done in Matlab, but gives me a lot of headache in Python.

My example code loos:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

#plt.ion()

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
#plt.show()

for n in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
    s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t-n*np.pi/3)
    plt.plot(t, s)
    #plt.show()
    plt.draw()
    raw_input('press a key')
```

This code only prints "press a key" 6 times. Yet, when I comment out "raw_input('press a key')" line, the figure is drawn instantaneously.

I tried plt.ion(), did not help. Also, there is no difference if I use plt.show() or plt.draw().

I'm stuck here... What am I doing wrong?

Can someone please suggest a (preferably simple) solution?

Comment: I'm using python 3, so perhaps not able to perfectly reproduce your problem. What I observe is that I need both `draw` and `show` for the figure to be drawn. Comment out either and nothing is drawn. BTW in `n*pi/3`, `pi` is not defined. You probably meant `np.pi`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a typo, should be "np.pi" (I will correct the original post.). Still, in my case it does not matter, if I use "draw", "show" or both. The result is always the same. Six times "press a key" message is printed, and at the end whole picture is drawn at once. By the way, I'm using Python 2.7.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add time and it should work.

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for n in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
    s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t-n*np.pi/3)
    plt.plot(t, s)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    raw_input('press a key')
```

Comment: It still does not work... Even when I remove `raw_input('press a key')` line, it just waits 6*N seconds (whee `time.sleep(N)`) and plots the whole figure at once

Comment: By the way I just discovered that it works when I call the script from the command line `python test.py`, but it does not work when started from the Spyder console. I'm using Spyder 2.2.4

Comment: I don't use Spider, so I don't know. But the script works well with python. Sorry Borris, could not help more.